# How to achieve multiple output representations in Django Rest Framework Serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use the Django Rest Framework(DRF)'s serializer with Djnago models with some PostgreSQL fields. I understand that by overriding `to_representation()` method of the serializer, the outgoing (serialized) data format can be changed. Is there any way to have multiple outgoing representations in DRF serializers? For example, what I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def to_representation_1(self, instance):
        return {
            'first_name': instance.first_name,
            'last_name': instance.last_name
        }
    
    def to_representation_2(self, instance):
        return {
            'firstName': instance.first_name,
            'lastName': instance.last_name
        }
    
    def to_representation_2(self, instance):
        return {
            'name': f'{instance.first_name} {instance.last_name}',
            
        }
```

Is there such support in DRF? If no, what is the recommended way to achieve this keeping the possibility of nested serializers in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I think `rest_framework.serializers.SerializerMethodField` may solve your problem.

You can use it like below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
    
    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

see: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: My requirement is more on changing the field name of the outgoing data format and excluding certain fields for certain outgoing representations. This solution does not quite address my issue.